# Get php object methology

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm wondering what is a better way to deal with getting an object.

1)

```
class UserInfo{
  private $UserName;
  private $UserID;
  }

function GetUserInfo($UserID){
  $User = new User();
  // something
  $User->UserName = "Arnold";
  return $User;
  }
```

2)

```
class UserInfo{
  private $UserName;
  private $UserID;

  public function GetUserInfo($UserID){
    // something
    $this->UserName = "Arnold";
    }
  }
```

Are there any major issues when using the second one?

Note this is highly simplified example :-)

Edit:  that is not really my question. Neither is using Magic setters/getters (which are bad imho). However I was wondering if there is some drawback in putting the object getter outside/inside the class. So I would be either calling it $User = GetUserInfo(1) or $User = new User(); $User->GetUserInfo(1)

Comment: PHP `__get` and `__set` magic methods could be used.

Comment: second method..you can not access private variables of class outside of class...create setter & getter method with second method

Answer (score 0):

**Visibility**

The visibility of a property or method can be defined by prefixing the declaration with the keywords public, protected or private. Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

**Property Visibility**

Class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Hi, that is not really my question. Neither is using Magic setters/getters (which are bad imho). However I was wondering if there is some drawback in putting the object getter outside/inside the class. So I would be either calling it $User = GetUserInfo(1) or $User = new User(); $User->GetUserInfo(1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Approach given in below solutions. Create Getter & Setter methods for private variables or Pass values in constructor to initialise values at the time of instantiation.

1.

```
class UserInfo{
    private $UserName;
    private $UserID;

    public function _setUserName($UserName){
        $this->UserName = $username;
    }

    public function _getUserName(){
        return $this->UserName;
    }

    public function _setUserId($UserID){
        $this->UserId = $UserID;
    }

    public function _getUserId(){
        return $this->UserId;
    }
}

$user = new UserInfo();
$user->_setUserName("Username Passed Here");
$user->_setUserID("UserId Passed here");
echo $user->_getUserName." ".$user->_getUserID;

or You can use constructor to set values at time of Object Instantiation like given below
```

1.

```
 class UserInfo{
    private $UserName;
    private $UserID;

    function __construct($UserName, $UserId){
         $this->UserName = $username;
         $this->UserId = $UserID;
    }

    public function _getUserName(){
        return $this->UserName;
    }

    public function _getUserId(){
        return $this->UserId;
    }
}

$user = new UserInfo("Username Passed Here", "UserID Passed Here");
echo $user->_getUserName." ".$user->_getUserID;
```